# custom protocol handler to launch IE - inconsistent results

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, protocol-handler

I am facing an issue in making the custom protocol handler to launch IE behave correctly.

Here is what i am trying to do:
I have my webpage that that users are required to access in chrome. The page has links to some external web-applications. These external web-applications work well only on Internet Explorer.
I have to somehow launch IE with the url of the external web-app on click of the link.

The customer is not open to utilizing plugins like IETab for launching these external applications.

Hence, i have tried to define a custom protocol handler which would get the target URL as a parameter and launch the internet explorer browser with the target URL.

It seems to work fine as long as there is no IE window already open. But behaves differently when there is already an instance of IE running.

I used the following code:

In the HTML file:

```
function launchIE(target){
window.location = "launchIE:\"http://external.url.com?param1=1&param2=2\"";
}
```

I have registered the handler to the custom protocol "launchIE" by adding the following into windows registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\launchIE]
"URL Protocol"="\"\""
@="\"URL:launchIE Protocol\"" 

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\launchIE\DefaultIcon] 
@="\"iexplore.exe,1\"" 

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\launchIE\shell]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\launchIE\shell\open]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\launchIE\shell\open\command] 
@="cmd /C set myvar=%1 & call set myvar=%%myvar:launchIE:=%% & call start /separate iexplore %%myvar%% & exit"
```

With the above setup, when i click the button to trigger the above javascript I get Internet Explorer launched.
The IE opens the URL http://external.url.com?param1=1&param2=2 correctly if there is no instance of Internet Explorer already open.
[screenshot of IE showing correct URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufrGJ.png)

But, if there is already an instance of IE opened (either manually by the user or due to a prior click on the button on my page), IE opens an incorrect URL http://%22http//external.url.com?param1=1&param2=2"
[screenshot of IE showing wrong URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5yn0.png)

Please help ... how should i fix this ?

I am working on windows 10 & IE 11.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by creating a separate batch file, and surrounding the URL with double quotes:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ie\shell\open\command]
@="cmd /C c:/tmp/ie.bat \"%1\" & exit"
```

ie.bat:

```
set var=%1
set var=%var:ie:=%
call start /separate iexplore %var%
exit
```